# Extjs TabPanel Auto Height is not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, tabpanel

Extjs TabPanel is Working on FireFox, Chrome & Safari with autoHeight While not in IE.

Comment: what does 'not working' mean?  What is your question? And where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok Let me explain it.....

```
var SessionTab = new Ext.TabPanel({
    id: 'tabpanel-session',
    activeTab: 0,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    forceLayout: true,
    resizeTabs: true,
    // applied on it's Child Components.....
    defaults: {
        style: 'font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'
    },
    // turn on tab resizing
    minTabWidth: 115,
    tabWidth: 190,
    enableTabScroll: true,
    width: '100%',
    autoHeight: true,
    deferredRender: false,
    layoutOnTabChange: true
});
```

I set autoHeight==true for (SessionTab) Tab Panel here it's showing Tab Panel items at other browsers fine except IE.

Here I am trying to Fill the Tab items in a Ajax Call.....

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    /* Add Session Tab */
    SessionTab.add({
        id: 'session-tab-panel' + i,
        title: SessionYear+i,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'searchPanel' // Search Panel
        },
        {
            xtype: 'detail' // Detail Panel
        }]
    });
}

SessionTab.setActiveTab(0);
SessionTab.show();
```

Comment: When you want to update your question, Please click on `edit` grayed link below tags of your question, and add this data below body of your question and delete this as answer ;).